# Translate Picture

Tags: translation

[image]

Hi can somebody translate accurately the meaning of this?

Please put the format in Original Korean Text and word by word translation and then the corresponding phrase translation. 
Regards

Comment: Hi - you have the first picture (i.e the top part of the picture) upside down.

Comment: thiis is astro message card from MJ PLWASE TRSNSLATE IT TO ME I DONT UNDERSTAND HANGUL!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWBWP.jpg)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ZMm.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

From [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=ko&tl=en&text=%EB%86%8D%ED%98%91%20%ED%96%85%EC%8C%80%20%EC%82%AC%EC%9A%A9%0A%0A%EA%B5%AD%EB%82%B4%EC%82%B0%20%EA%B9%80%EC%9D%84%20%EC%82%AC%EC%9A%A9%ED%95%98%EC%98%80%EC%8A%B5%EB%8B%88%EB%8B%A4%0A%0A%EB%B6%80%EC%A0%95.%EB%B6%84%EB%9F%89%EC%8B%9D%ED%92%88%20%EC%8B%A0%EA%B3%A0%EB%8A%94%20%EA%B5%AD%EB%B2%88%EC%97%86%EC%9D%B4%201399):

농협 햅쌀 사용
<s>Nonghyup New Year rice</s>
농협 - **농**업**협**동조합 - farmer's association
햅쌀 - current year's newly harvested rice
사용 - used in production of this product
-> Nonghyup's newly harvested rice was used in this product

국내산 김을 사용하였습니다
Domestic sea weed was used
국내산 - domestic product
김 - sea weed
사용하였습니다 - was used
 -> Domestic sea weed was used (in this product)

부정.불량식품 신고는 국번없이 1399
<s>1399 without food registration number</s>
부정 - abnormal (defective)
불량 - bad/defective
식품 - food product
신고 - report
국번없이 - excluding national area code
1399 - one three nine nine (telephone number)
 -> call 1399 to report defective product

Comment: Sorry for the reversed picture. I would like to.confirm a few things, 1) 농협 is the abbreviation of a farmers association, in Korea (Country)? 2) 햅쌀 is this some kind of kanji Korea? 3) Is Nonghyup's the romanized name of the association? 4) What is the meaning of "Kim" in "Domestic Kim"? 5) You missed the character 을 in 김을 what does it.mean? 6) you also left the following characters in your answer 식품 and 는? Regards

Comment: 1) yes 2) no 3) yes 4) as written, Kim = 김 - sea weed 5) 을 is a Korean grammatical particle and doesn't have an English translation (like 'the' wouldn't have a corresponding translation in many languages) you will need to know basic Korean sentence structure to understand what it means 6) 식품 - food product, 는 - same as 5

Comment: BTW it's 불량 (defective), not 분량 (quantity).

Comment: what is the English name for kim anyway? Does it even have a common name in English?

Comment: Am I wrong ? 김 is sea weed (some plant in sea)

Comment: @HKLee it's correct, but I was wondering if 김 had a specific English name than generic sea weed. Or is it that any sea weed is called 김?

Comment: @Tom you can translate kim as just seaweed

Comment: @user17915 I see. You are right.

Comment: Also just to confirm, is 농업협동조합 an association or is it some kind of company, it is weird for me that an "association" is also producing product?

Comment: @Tomsofty33 : Closest meaning : I find a product in my house. It contains English description : traditional seaweed (재래돌김). And ingredient : Seaweed

Comment: @Tomsofty33 : 농협=NH=National agricultural cooperative federation. In my thought, we can view it as a company, for instance, samsung. But NH mainly deals farmer's production and related things.

Comment: 김 is a particular kind of seaweed: a package of 김 is sometimes marked as _nori_ (after Japanese) or laver. I think 김 and _nori_ are basically the same thing; not sure about laver, which is apparently a Welsh ingredient. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gim_(food) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nori https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laver_(seaweed)

Comment: By the way, 김 and other edible seaweeds are algae, which are technically not plants. :)